# How to link from a diagram to a script

Tags: enterprise-architect

Imagine you have a diagram in Sparx Enterprise Architect and you would like to provide a button or link to start some kind of script.

I know that there are diagram-type scripts which can be accessed through the context menu of a diagram but I would like to present the user of a diagram a button or  link to execute a certain script.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box. EA allows you to create hyperlinks which run any one of a fairly large set of EA commands, but this set does not include the ability to run an arbitrary script.

What you can do is create a stereotype and an Add-In which catches the `EA_OnContextItemDoubleClicked` event and, after checking the stereotype, performs the desired function.

Note that the EA API does not allow you to run an arbitrary script either, so you'll have to implement the function separately in the Add-In.

Comment: thanx. So my solution now is to use a batch-file in order to invoke the script as external one...